# activemq simple user authentication

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using apache activemq in a project that involves communication with an android app , that is running an mqtt service.
My problem is very simple and I can't imagine that no solution exists, given that this is the same question several people have, when dealing with any client-server communication protocol.

I do not know how to implement simple user authentication in activemq. I have been through the docs and they specify usernames and passwords in xml files. That is fine if you have three or four users, but meaningless when you consider thousands of users on my app.

I then read up on interceptor plugins, but the documentation on these is very thin. 
Specifically I want to know where I can find open-source implementations or example plugins that intercept a message --> pass it to my business logic(bean) , my bean authenticates the user ---> returns a message to the user saying access denied OR passes the message on as desired. LDAP does not make much sense, all I want is to be able to do a simple username and password lookup, before relaying the message onwards.

Look forward to any constructive suggestions/links/books.

Regards,
Richard.

Comment: where do you plan on managing your user credentials?

Comment: Titan graph db. I have an instance connected to my webapp, although it doesnt really matter where, as long as I have a method to actually perform custom business logic on the connection.

Comment: assuming you have a JDBC connector for this db, one possibility would be to use a JAAS plugin which authenticates using jdbc calls.  i know that jetty has [such a module](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/JAAS#JDBCLoginModule), which i don't think requires any other jetty dependencies.

Comment: actually, i could be wrong about the dependencies, but it's apache licensed code, so you could copy the code and rip out the jetty dependencies.

Comment: So does the JAAS authentication plug-in not meet your requirements?